# Annotate method in ES6 class without using arrow function

Tags: typescript

I have a class defined like so:

```
export type ClassMethod = (( param1: number ) => void)

export class Class {
    method(param1: number): void {
        console.log(param1)
    }
}
```

I am exporting `method`'s type definition because I'm passing `method` (as part of an actual `Class` instance) to another class somewhere in the code, and I wouldn't be able to tell `method`'s definition on the receiving end if I didn't do so:

```
const class = new Class()
const otherClass = new OtherClass(Class.method)

/*

otherClass will use `method` in its implementation, and I would like to access its definition within
OtherClass' definition, so currently I'm importing `ClassMethod` from the file where `Class` is defined

/*
```

This has the obvious drawback of leaving `method`'s definition within `Class`' definition not coupled with `ClassMethod`, and would require me to remember to change `ClassMethod`'s definition every time I change `method`'s signature.

One solution would be to define `method` as an arrow function, which will allow me to annotate its type within `Class`' definition:

```
export type ClassMethod = (( param1: number ) => void)

export class Class {
    method: ClassMethod = (param1): void => {
        console.log(param1)
    }
}
```

However this would force the binding of `this` within `method` to the class instance. Which I don't want to do currently (I'm aware this doesn't really make a difference in this simplified example, the example is just to get my point across)

So other than defining `method` within `Class`' constructor, which is a bit ugly, is there any other way to annotate method without changing the "neutral" binding of `this`?

Hope I explained everything clearly. Thanks!

Comment: I am very unsure why you are going through all of this when you can use `type ClassMethod = Class["method"];`

Comment: @kelly I'm not sure either. I'm very new to typescript and even though I've done type mapping by referencing a nested property like that with plain objects, it didn't occur to me that I could've done the same for a class. I knew I was missing something trivial. I guess maybe it would be useful to keep the question up for somebody else, so if you care to provide an answer I'll accept it and give you credit for it. Thanks!